# error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs form the type of the dummy argument, [A]

Tags: fortran

I'm new to Fortran and have experiences with Fortran 95 and Python.I've got this program in FORTRAN 77 that I need to work on for my job. I've got the source code, but there's no documentation or extra files like makefiles to help me compile it. I ran into a bunch of errors when I tried to compile it using VS 2015. I think the problem is that the arguments I defined don't match the parameters used in the subroutine calls. The thing is, I can't find where the parameter types are defined in the program. The code uses common blocks (`COMMON`), but they don't specify the data types, which is pretty different from the Fortran 95 that I'm used to. So now I'm stuck because I don't know how to adjust my compiler settings to get this program to compile properly. Here's some of the code that's giving me trouble.
the define of A

```
      COMMON /VARDIM/ A(8000000)                                        VSO  220
```

the error line

```
      CALL START3(A(KA(LJAD1)))                                         VSO 2640
```

the define of parameters in START3

```
      SUBROUTINE START3(JAD11)                                          RT3   10
      ......
      DIMENSION JAD11(JD11)                                             RT3  410
      ......
      RETURN                                                            RT3 1150
      END                                                               RT3 1160
```

Understand the logic of error reporting

Determine the compiler Settings：language-->Source File Format-->Use File Extension(so the setting includes the fixed format); language-->Fixed Form Line Length-->72 Colunmns(so the setting make sure the length of line is correct)

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask] and [mcve]. Always use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Common blocks are also.valid and sometimes used in Fortran 95 and are even.part of Fortran 2018.

Comment: If `A` is typed implicitly it could be real, and if `jad11` is typed implicitly it could be integer. (We don't know, because you aren't showing the typing rules in force.) Those aren't the same type, so we would expect a mismatch error, if the compiler knows. The usual solution when a compiler flags up broken code is to correct the code, not get the compiler to accept the broken code and hope it does what you want it to do.

Comment: @Francescalus in therory you're right, but some "broken codes" have sometimes been worjing correctly for decades, and in the case of a big code, fixing it can be a long task... In the past it was not uncommon to pass a real array to be used as integers, or vice versa. And most of the compilers wouldn't complain. So, at first, finding compiler switches that allow compiling the code is not a completly bad idea.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Yes, @PierU, and yet from the detail in the question we have absolutely no way of telling whether this is one of the good or bad ways of working around a different compiler's diagnostic ability.